# Rewrite function without 'while' or any loop

Tags: r

Here is a function that returns several rows from airquality table. Rows format is day/month that consist max value of temperature. How I can rewrite function without `while` or any other loop?

```
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
> 

maxTemp_func <- function(days) {
    Myframe <- as.data.frame(airquality)
    l <- list()
    x <- 1 
    while (x <= days) {
        NewData <-  Myframe[Myframe[, "Temp"] == max(Myframe$Temp), ]
        mydata <- c("Month->", head( NewData[["Month"]], 1), "Day->", head( NewData[["Day"]], 1), "Temperature->", head(NewData[["Temp"]] , 1))
        l[[x]] <- mydata
        Myframe <- Myframe[!(Myframe$Temp == head( max(Myframe$Temp), 1)),]
        x <- x + 1
    }
    return(l)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the hottest days in `airquality`, just do this:

```
maxTemp_func <- function(days) {
    temp_order <- order(-airquality[["Temp"]])
    airquality[temp_order[seq_len(days)], c("Month", "Day", "Temp")]
}
```

Your function actually does not do this, since it finds all rows tied for highest temperature, saves the first row from them, then removes all of them. So if two rows are tied for hottest day, one of them will not be the second hottest.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain in a few words the sence of order here? We sort all values from airquality depends on Temp column in descending order and then takes the top rows. Is it right?

Comment: Correct. `seq_len(days)` returns the sequence `1`, `2`, ..., `days`. It's safer than `1:days`, which is `c(1, 0)` when `days` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Returning max temperature values for each month and day using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)    
output <- airquality %>%
    group_by(Month, Day) %>%
    summarise(max_temp = max(Temp))
```

EDIT: to return `x` highest temperatures for the entire dataset.

```
N = {insert val here}
output <- airquality %>%
  group_by(Month, Day) %>%
  mutate(max_temp = max(Temp)) %>%
  arrange(desc(max_temp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(1:N)
```

Comment: So how I can return 5 pairs? For example I post to function 8 so I have 8 pairs with max temperatures, I post 5 so I have 5 pairs with max temperatures. > maxTemp_func(3)
[[1]]
[1] "Month->"       "8"             "Day->"         "28"            "Temperature->" "97"           

[[2]]
[1] "Month->"       "8"             "Day->"         "30"            "Temperature->" "96"           

[[3]]
[1] "Month->"       "8"             "Day->"         "29"            "Temperature->" "94"           

>

Comment: to clarify... you are looking to return the 'x' highest temperatures for each month?

Comment: I post to function amount of days. For example 5. This function should return to me 5 rows (day, month) in which the Temp value is the highest. So i'm looking to return the 'x' rows of day-month format that have highest temp values

Comment: So, using your example, you want the 5 highest temp values for the entire dataset? Or the 5 highest temp values for each day?

Comment: the 5 highest temp values for the entire dataset. Actually I don't need temp values. I need pairs Day/Month (with highest temp)

Comment: See updated answer, do you need this in function format?

Comment: If one of the answers provided solved your issue please accept that answer to close out the question.